# Writing tab spaced words to a file in Python

Tags: python

I have a set of words in a file. I want to add a new character separated by tab to all these words and write to a new file. 
The code I wrote is

```
#file to read is opened as ff and file to write is opened as fw.
count = "X"
x = ff.readlines()
for word in x:
     fw.write('%s\t%s'% (word, count))
     fw.write("\n")
```

The problem is the new word 'X' is not alignment with the existing words. The sample output i am getting is

```
 A.
      O
 Mahesh
      O
 Anand
      O
 Anton
      O
 Plot
```

The output I want is:

```
Original File
word
word2

New File 
word    X
word2    X
```

I want it to be aligned properly

Comment: see [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) module

Comment: Show some lines of both original file and new file. It would be easy to debug then...

Comment: You can use the width option in the format string: `"%-10s%s"` for example, to get the formatting to add the spacing you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines()` includes the end of line characters:

```
In [6]: ff.readlines()
Out[6]: ['word1\n', 'word2']
```

You need to [strip them off](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip):

```
word = word.rstrip()
```

---

```
count = "X"
with open('data', 'r') as ff, open('/tmp/out', 'w') as fw:
    for word in ff:
        word = word.rstrip()  # strip only trailing whitespace
        fw.write("{}\t{}\n".format(word, count))
```

Comment: The `readlines` function returns a list of lines in the given file along with the newline character(`\n`) at the end of each element.
This is the reason your code resulted in the tab being inserted in the next line.

The `rstrip` function removes this trailing newline character before you concatenate your new character to it.

Comment: @unutbu I also changed string interpolation(`%`) to use the more preferred system using `format`

Answer (score 0):

use `str.rstrip()` as to remove end of line `\n`.

use `context manager` `with` statement to open the file, 
and use `str.formate` to write in file.

```
with open('out_file.txt') as ff, open('in_file.txt', 'w+') as r:
    for line in ff:
        r.write('{}\t{!r}\n'.format(line.rstrip(), 'X'))
    r.seek(0)
    print r.read()

>>> 
   word1    'X'
   word2    'X'
   word3    'X'
   word4    'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remove '\n':

```
count = "X"
with open('data', 'r') as ff, open('/tmp/out', 'w') as fw:
    for word in ff.readlines():
        print >> fw, '%s\t%s' % (word.rstrip(), count)
```